# EntityException: Access to the database file is not allowed

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, setup-project, setup-deployment

I am working on a Visual Sudio 2010 Setup Project to install an Entity Framework / SQL Compact app. The app needs to install an SDF file on the user's machine. As I understand the Microsoft guidance, I should install the SDF file to a company\application subfolder under C:\ProgramsData on the user's machine, which I have done in the setup project by creating a custom folder in the File System Editor with a DefaultLocation property of [CommonAppDataFolder]. All works well, and the SDF file is installed to C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyApp\MyFile.sdf.

Here is my problem: On the client machine, my app is throwing an EntityException with the following message: "SqlCeException: Access to the database file is not allowed." Sounds like a permissions issue.

Is there a way to set permissions on the SDF installation folders from within a VS Setup project? How would I do it? Any examples? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a small DLL that gets executed as a Custom Action by the Visual Studio Setup Project. There is a walkthrough on creating Custom actons [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(VS.100).aspx).